# creating and playing a .wav file simultaneously

Tags: node.js

How can we play a wav file in a live stream manner in node.js?

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't.

If possible [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) the audio data between the processes (directly or using a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) aka. FIFO).

Possible issues you may encounter writing and reading simultaneosly:

- Windows will flat out refuse to open a file that's being written to, if I recall correctly
- Wav files have a length value before the audio data, and most wav writers will insert it only after the audio data has been written. So until the file is finished it will be filled with a garbage value.
- If your reader is faster than your writer, your file will suddenly end.